# How to put the max value of a column for a each page on the header in CR

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a crystal report, which lists street names.
The report is ordered by street name.
In the header of the report I need to specify the first street name on the page, and the last street name on the page.

How can I do this?

Technically, this is the max and min of the street name, however it may be useful to know it is the first and last entry on the page.

The data comes from an excel document, and the version of crystal is 10.

FYI this is my first report with Crystal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I misunderstood your question:

This is going to sound a little odd, but I think the only way to do this in your Report Header is to insert a SubReport into the Report Header. This is due to the order in which the Report Header evaluates compared to the rest of the report.

When you insert the Subreport, choose an existing report. Select the report you are currently working on as it's own SubReport.

Now, in the Subreport, suppress everything except the detail row. Selectively suppress the detail row using this formula:

```
not OnFirstRecord and not OnLastRecord
```

It will leave you with two detail records in your Report Header. The first and the last records of your report.